# SciPy - Distinguish between two group of periodic samples

Tags: fft, dft, scipy, sensor

*First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English writing, plus, I'm new to DSP.*

## Background

We have got motion data of 20 cows. 10 cows are healthy and 10 cows are slightly lame.

> Lameness is an abnormal gait or stance of an animal that is the result of dysfunction of the locomotor system... [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lameness_(equine))

It is expected to observe a significant difference in locomotion data, recorded from these 20 cows. Data has been collected using an electronic sensor consist of Angular velocity ($\omega: rad/s$) and Linear acceleration ($a: m/s^2$). As it was expected, data is periodic:

[image]
*Vectors axis: X(Red), Y(Green), Z(Blue).*
*Up: Angular velocity ($rad/s$) over time ($ms$).*
*Down: Linear acceleration ($m/s^2$) over time ($ms$).*

---

Each period, represents a step of cow.

## Question

I want to perform a comparison between these two group of data to find out the significant difference between lame and non-lame cows. My question is **what is/are choice approach(es) to perform this comparison? Is there a standard test to choose the approach according to the signal data?**

My best hypotheses:

- Maybe some of primary data properties be useful. (e.g average, standard deviation, extremums, etc.)
- Try to use Fourier transform of data. But I have no idea about this one. (*Please guide me if it's possible*).
- Try to use derivative or integral of time series. For example, maybe the Angular acceleration ($\alpha: rad/s^2$) is preferable.

Thanks in advance.

### Update

These are some other plots:

*Normal:*
[image: Normal cow (2)]

*Lame:*
[image: Lame cow (1)]

*Lame:*
[image: Lame cow (2)]

Comment: This may be a good machine learning classification problem. It looks like you only posted a plot for a good cow, can you post a plot for a lame cow as well?

Comment: @DanBoschen Sure. btw, there are some differences between plots, due to individual differences.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I can't see anything obviously different in the plots to know what to even look for, hence I think a good application as an AI/ machine learning classification problem - hopefully someone with more experience in that can comment.

Comment: This is an incredibly open ended question and it would definitely benefit from editing for focus. The key thing to determine here is: What are *"...significant difference between lame and non-lame cows..."*? Are you looking to classify lame-non lame? Are you looking to find those waveform features that are different between lame-non lame cows? Are you looking to classify the cows into lame-non-lame or are you looking into analysing these data to determine gait differences and from there infer something about the condition of the cow?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As you say, I'm looking to classify cows in lame ane non-lame groups.

Comment: Is there a possibility to upload some csv files with the data, so people can try algorithms?